# Is it possible to center a relative positioned div that contains an absolute positioned div?

Tags: javascript, css

boilerplate html/css/etc.

then

```
<div>

    <div style="margin:0 auto; position:relative">
        <div data-item data-ng-repeat="item in ItemCtrl.item"></div>
    </div>

</div>
```

... the above uses an Angular template, which is incredibly simple. It just positions absolutely my content into one, two, or three columns. If I set the screen to two columns I'd like it to be centered. I'm able to do this via code, but I wanted a more fluid feel and I suspect CSS can do this, but I'm having trouble w/it.

Here's my template:

```
<div style="width:400px">
    Content here ...
</div>
```

My Angular directive simply grabs the element above and changes its CSS position property to absolute and gives it a top and left property.

Why is this not working? Can this be done?

So in essence if I have one column, which is 400px and is put in my display at position 0, which would occur in this case, and the screen is at 1400px, I'd like the containing div to be displayed at x position (1400-400)/2.

If I have two columns, which are 400px and are put on my display at positions 0 and 410, which would also occur in this case, and the screen is at 1400px, I'd like the containing div to be displayed at x position (1400-810)/2.

UPDATE:
Here's a fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/0LLa1rs4/

UPDATE:
Here's a solution, although I'm not sure it's the most elegant. Any suggestions to make it better are welcome.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head lang="en">
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title></title>
</head>

<body>
    <div style="background-color:blue; position:relative; width:100%; margin:20px auto;">
testing ...


        <div style="position:absolute; width:400px; left:50%; margin-left:-200px">
            <div style="top:100px; left:0px; width:400px; background-color:green; position:absolute">
                Item #1
            </div>

            <div style="top:200px; left:0px; width:400px; background-color:green; position:absolute">
                Item #2
            </div>
        </div>



    </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Can you show us any additional CSS, or maybe add a fiddle that shows more clearly what you're doing and why you think it doesn't work? Also, instead of using terms like "display position" could you be more precise and say `left:1400px` or `transform: translateX(1400px)`

Comment: Thanks Patrick, here's a JSFiddle http://jsfiddle.net/0LLa1rs4/

Comment: I'm still not sure what you're trying to achieve.

Comment: why is this tagged angular and javascript when it's nothing more than a css question?

Comment: @charlietfl I re-tagged to remove angular, but js is still valid because the original solution by OP was JS based.

Answer (score 0):

Well I'm not sure what you're trying to achieve, you jsfiddle is not very clear. Do you want the number of columns to be dynamic or you choose it? I've made a jsfiddle that could answer the issue but I'm not sure:

http://jsfiddle.net/0LLa1rs4/1/

Basically you should play with

```
display: flex;
```

And on the child element

```
margin: auto;
```

Answer (score 0):

From your fiddle, it looks like you're trying to center elements horizontally within a container. Your description camouflages this.

Here's a simple fiddle that does similar things to the fiddle you posted, but in a much more concise way: http://jsfiddle.net/gunderson/5eLx4r4p/1/

HTML

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="item">Item 0</div>
    <div class="item">Item 1</div>
</div>
```

CSS

```
.container{
    margin: 20px;
    width: 100%;
}

.item{
    width: 400px;
    margin: 20px auto; /* margin (horizontal) auto is what does the centering, as long as width is defined */
    background: green;
}
```

Comment: Thanks Patrick, but I have two divs I'm working w/here. The outer div and the inner div, which itself has multiple elements that get absolutely positioned within ... so I need the entire inner div to be centered horizontally w/all the containing elements.

Comment: So, you have a container that has a number of divs that you want to be centered. Then within those divs you have some absolutely positioned elements? `<container><item centered><absolute></absolute><absolute></absolute></item></container>` ?